# Convert regex string to regex object that contains unicode character class escape

Tags: javascript, regex, object, unicode-escapes

I have a data object with regex in it

```
data = {regex : "/^[\p{L} .’_-]+$/u"}
```

In js file I am using this pattern to match with a string

```
var s = "check";
var pattern = new RegExp(data.regex);
console.log(pattern.test(s));
```

The above code is not working. Pattern becomes //^[p{L} .’_-]+$/u/ and is resulting to false and extra slashes are also getting attached to the regex.

How to fix this so the result can be something like this
pattern = /^[\p{L} .’_-]+$/u but in regex object?

Also, there is a difference when console.log of values takes place.

```
const [, regexx, flags] = regex.match(/^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$/);
const pattern = new RegExp(regexx, flags);
console.log(pattern); //  /^[\p{L} .’_-]+$/u


var sampleregex = /^[\p{L} .’_-]+$/u
console.log(sampleregex) //  /^(?:[ \x2D\.A-Z_a-z\xAA\xB5\x....
```

Why is so and how to make pattern variable behave the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the backslash in your regex string `\p{L}` has been escaped. You might need a regex to match the regex, and extract the regex string and flags such as:

```
^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$
```

Here's a running example:

```js
const data = { regex : "/^[\\p{L} .’_-]+$/u" };

// extract the regex string and flags(optional)
const [, regex, flags] = data.regex.match(/^\/(.*)\/([a-z]*)$/);

const s = "check";
const pattern = new RegExp(regex, flags);

console.log(pattern);
console.log(pattern.test(s));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. There was one more question related to this, I have updated the question above, hope you can help in that?

Comment: @RifaFatima It looks like your regex is somehow got polyfilled into a more compatible version (which does not support `u` flag). Do you maybe have a bundling tool like webpack and set the target browser to IE? (e.g. `"target": "es5"`)

Comment: Yes, in my angular.json file, I do have this  "es5": {
              "browserTarget": "es5"
            }
How can I fix this?

Comment: @RifaFatima Change it from `es5` to `es6` should solve this problem (a rebuild is required).